# Interpreting non linear brms output - estimates of posterior cooefficient and user supplied formula

Tags: bayesian, interpretation, model, nonlinear-regression, brms

I am a bit confused about how to approximate the equation from a nonlinear model constructed in brms, and was hoping someone could explain it to me.

Say I have the below model:

```
 Family: lognormal 
  Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity 
Formula: weight.g ~ b1^b2 
         b1 ~ 1 + dia.1.cm
         b2 ~ 1
   Data: CaesCombBot.data.wfrag (Number of observations: 2619) 
Samples: 4 chains, each with iter = 5000; warmup = 2000; thin = 5;
         total post-warmup samples = 2400

Population-Level Effects: 
             Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
b1_Intercept     6.61      0.81     5.08     8.24 1.00     1741     1787
b1_dia.1.cm      0.98      0.42     0.42     2.07 1.00     1738     1974
b2_Intercept     0.57      0.06     0.46     0.70 1.00     1727     1942

Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sigma     0.56      0.01     0.54     0.57 1.00     2156     2105

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

I'm assuming that the supplied formula represents something along the lines of (int + ax)^b - but when I try to place the estimates back into the equation, they appear to do a poor job of approximating the model displayed.

For example:

```
curve((6.61 + 0.98*x)^0.57, from = 0, to = 50)
```

[image: curve]

Just doing a quick comparison: x value of 40 (6.61 + 0.98*40)^0.57 = exp(8.846) [modelled in lognormal dist] = 6946.547

Compared to x value of 40 corresponding to 5256.29 according to add_predictions for model

[image: model]

I understand they visually appear different as one is on the log scale while one is on the response scale, but shouldn't the values roughly match up at least?

I feel as though I am probably missing something very obvious and fundamental, would be very grateful for any help or insight.